# How to update a Lambda function with new code (without CodeDeploy)?

Tags: aws-lambda

I have SAM installed on my Linux machine.

I updated some code in my infrastructure and need the new code updated in the Lambda.

I'm not using CodeDeploy, and I don't want to use it. Not yet anyway.

What is the proper way to propagate this updated code to my Lambda function?

Comment: Do you use AWS toolkit ?

Comment: No. I find the CLI simpler.

Comment: Does this solves your problem ? : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html

Comment: That's the answer I found using DuckDuckGo, so I think it is. Just need to install AWS cli.

Comment: Yes, because if you are comfortable with CLI you can go with this solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html

```
aws lambda update-function-code \
    --function-name  my-function \
    --zip-file fileb://my-function.zip
```

You can use the above syntax to update your lambda code directly.